# $D_x^nD_y^mD_z^s(y^me^z+x^ne^z)=e^z$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

My teacher asked whether $D_x^nD_y^mD_z^s(y^me^z+x^ne^z)=e^z$ is correct?

My answer is false and $D_x^nD_y^mD_z^s(y^me^z+x^ne^z)=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: What does $s$ represent here?

Comment: If both $m,n$ are positive, you are right.

Comment: $m,n,s$ are positive integers

Comment: Try $D^2_x x^2=2$ and generalize.